# What is acpitz-virtual?

Tags: linux, acpi, lm-sensors

`lm-sensors` gives the following output for this machine:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +60.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)                  
temp2:       +56.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)                  
temp3:       +35.3°C  (crit = +105.0°C)                  
temp4:       +75.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)                  
temp5:       +65.0°C  (crit = +256.0°C)                  
temp6:       +63.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)                  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)  

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 1:      +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I would like to know what the `acpitz-virtual` sensor is.
It seems to be some sort of replication of acpi thermal zones but `/proc/acpi` only contains

```
ac_adapter
battery
button
event
wakeup
```

so there don't seem to be any temperature sensors.
Can somebody make sense of this?

Answer (score 14):

## What does the `acpitz-virtual` sensor output refer to?

The `acpitz` refers to the 'ACPI thermal zone'. There was [some discussion about renaming the thermal zones on the `lm-sensors` mailing list](http://marc.info/?l=lm-sensors&m=121938086228303):

> We could probably update the code so that the labels default to the ACPI thermal zone names. Sometimes these names are useful... but
>   sometimes not.

From the same reply above, there is a way too look up the ACPI table (with a caveat):

> Look in /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/device/path. The last item of
>   the path is the device name. But as said above, these are 4-digit names
>   for ACPI internal use, usually not meaningful enough for humans.

Other `acpitz-virtual` outputs can refer to the [CPU socket temperature](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/339453-28-what-tepmeratures-represent) (see also [`Thermal sensors` on the ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Thermal_Sensors) or the [base](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/7607/how-to-identify-lm_sensors-output/) of [the CPU](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/lm-sensors-acpitz-virtual-0-adapter-virtual-device-temp1-what-is-it-749701/#post3655880), as per [this Ubuntu forums post](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1680239.html):

> "acpitz-virtual-0" is probably a sensor diode either in the CPU socket, or nearby on the motherboard.

Comment: Temp1 on acpitz-virtual-0 is almost always the CPU or CPU socket temperature. 

However, the other temperatures could be anywhere on the motherboard.

In particular, on this case temp4 is likely the Voltage Regulator FET block or the battery temp (if it's a laptop) due to the high temperature and slightly higher operating temperature tolerance.